Tkinter UI auto enlarges after changing style
So, I followed an online video, and tried to replicate the UI, while applying my own changes to fit my needs, but I ended up with a UI that keeps enlarging every time I change the theme.
I tried commenting some parts of the code, to see where the problem lies, but to no avail, I'm pretty new to Tkinter, but I can handle my way after seeing a couple of examples, but this error, I couldn't understand.
This is what it looks like:
https://youtu.be/3K3HWjYSB5s
And here's a working code snippet:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def toggle_mode():
    if mode_switch.instate(["selected"]):
        style.theme_use("forest-light")
    else:
        style.theme_use("forest-dark")


def select(event=None):
    treeview.selection_toggle(treeview.focus())
    print(treeview.selection())


root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Generator')

#root.geometry("1280x720")

style = ttk.Style(root)

root.tk.call("source", "Theme/forest-dark.tcl")

root.tk.call("source", "Theme/forest-light.tcl")

style.theme_use("forest-dark")

frame = ttk.Frame(root)

frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH) #Expand the frame to fill the root window

widgets_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Title 2")

widgets_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

mode_switch = ttk.Checkbutton(widgets_frame, text="Mode", style="Switch", command=toggle_mode)

mode_switch.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

separator = ttk.Separator(widgets_frame)

separator.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20, 0), pady=5, sticky="ew")

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text="Generate")#, command=todo)

button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

treeFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Title 1")

treeFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(treeFrame)

treeScroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

cols = ("1", "2", "3", "4")

treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeFrame, show=("headings"), selectmode="none", yscrollcommand=treeScroll.set, columns=cols, height=13)

treeview.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", select)

treeview.column("1", width=100)

treeview.column("2", width=150)

treeview.column("3", width=300)

treeview.column("4", width=100)

treeview.pack()

treeview.pack_propagate(False)

treeScroll.config(command=treeview.yview)

#load_data()

root.mainloop()


Your indentation is off! pleas edit the code block to represent the right indentation

Add stretch=0 in those treeview.column(...).

@acw1668, it worked! What I tried before was completely removing those lines, and it didn't work, but adding the stretsh=0 worked!! Please add it as an answer, and I'll accept it ^_^

It seems like the size of the treeview columns are changed whenever theme is changed.  You can disable the size change of those columns by adding stretch=0 to those treeview.column(...):
treeview.column("1", width=100, stretch=0)
treeview.column("2", width=150, stretch=0)
treeview.column("3", width=300, stretch=0)
treeview.column("4", width=100, stretch=0)

